# How to solve the following equation in $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given an $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, how do I approach to solving the following equation:

$a^x \equiv a^y \mod n$

I think that from here I can deduce that:

$x \equiv y \mod \varphi (n)$

But if so, I do not know why? Could someone assist with an explanation?

Comment: This is wrong for $a=0$ or $a=1$. You should assume at least $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Even this is not enough, take e.g. $2^2 \equiv 2^6 \pmod {15}$ but $2 \not \equiv 6 \pmod 8$.

Comment: The implication holds precisely if $a$ is a primitive root of $n$. Most $n$ do not have a primitive root. And even in the case when $n$ is prime, $a$ is not necessarily a primitive root of $n$,

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Can you explain a bit on the part when $n$ is prime and $a$ not a primitive root?

Comment: What about the following suggestion for a proof?
$a^{x-y}  \equiv 1 \mod n$ 
And from Euler's theorem we know that $a^{\varphi(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n$, thus:
$$ \varphi (n)  | x-y$$

Hence making it:
$$ x\equiv y \mod \varphi(n) $$
I understand the counter-example by @gammatester , but don't where my proof fails? $\\$ (I'm assuming $\gcd (a,n)=1$)

Comment: Your proof is correct if the hypothesis is for *all* $a\in\Bbb Z_n$. For a particular $a$, it is not true (say $a=1$).

Comment: You are misquoting Euler's Theorem. If $\varphi(n)$ divides $x-y$ then the congruence holds. But the converse is not true. Take for example $n=7$. We have $2^3\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, but $\varphi(7)$ does not divide $3$.

Comment: $\phi(n)$ is obviously the maximum order all $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n$, but for general $a, n$ it may be smaller, in my example $\mathrm{order}(2,15)=4$ and not 8. If $a$ is a primitive root (as A. Nicolas suggested)  the order of $a$ **is** $\phi(n)$ .

Comment: @QuangHoang: The assumption $a^x\equiv a^y\pmod{n}$ for all $a$ relatively prime to $n$ does not imply that $\varphi(n)$ divides $x-y$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so my proof would have been correct if instead of $\varphi(n)$ I would have written the order of $a$?

Comment: Yes, if $a^x\equiv a^y\pmod{n}$, where $a$ is relatively prime to $n$, then the order of $a$ divides $x-y$.

Answer (score 1):

Even the much stronger assumption that $a^x\equiv a^y \pmod{n}$ does not imply that $\varphi(n)$ divides $x-y$. For example, let $n=15$. Then $\varphi(n)=8$. However, if $a$ is relatively prime to $15$, then $a^4\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ and $a^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, so $a^4\equiv 1\pmod{15}$.

For more information, please search for the [*Carmichael function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) and *least universal exponent*.